# Problems with stored procedures and composite key

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am writing a stored procedure for insert and update and I don't know how to add composite key to procedure.

For insert:

```
create procedure sp_ParagraphInoviceInsert
    (@pName nvarchar(255),
     @pPrice nvarchar (255),
     @pDeviceID int,
     @pServiceID int,
     @pDate date,
     @pBillID int   ---->This is the other part of composite key, do I add here?
    )
as 
begin
    begin transaction
        insert into ParagraphInovice(Name, Price, device, service, date, bilID)
        values(@pname, @pPrice,....)

        if @@ERROR <> 0
        begin
            rollback
        end
        else 
        begin
            commit
        end
end
```

Update

```
create procedure sp_ParagraphInoviceUpdate
    (@pParagraphInoviceID int,
     @pName nvarchar(255),
     @pPrice nvarchar (255),
     @pDeviceID int,
     @pServiceID int,
     @pDate date,
     @pBillID int)
as 
begin
    begin transaction
        update ParagraphInovice 
        set name = @pName,
            price = @pPrice,
            device = @pDeviceID,
            service = @pServiceID,
            date = @pDate,
            billID = @pBillID   
        where 
            ParagraphInoviceID = @pParagraphInoviceID

        if @@ERROR <> 0
        begin
            rollback
        end
        else 
        begin
            commit
        end
    end
    go
```

So my table is made of composite keys ParagraphInovice (main) and bill (composite).

What is wrong with this procedure?

Thanks,

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: It's quite difficult to understand your problem. For update statement you (most likely) need to have all the keys that make up your primary key, and for insert you need to have at least all the fields that are non-nullable in the table.

Comment: I just want to know is this procedure ok (because I have composite key, I am still learning and I know to write with one primary key)
For Insert, do I composite part from other table add into INSERT INTO part?
For update: do I need to add composite part(billID) into where part or not?

Comment: For insert, you need to have all the fields in the `into` part, and the values for the fields in same order in the `values` part. For update (assuming your key values can't change) you need to have the all the key fields in `where` part, and the rest (that you want to update) in the `set`part.

Comment: Ok, got it, thank you